# Lib2to3 displaying an error in cmd

Tags: python

I lib2to3 when I try to convert a python 2 source file to a python 3 file it gives me an error when I try to convert it.

For instance:

```
2to3 -w MineCraft.py
```

gives me this error:

```
At least one file or directory arguement is required
Use --help to show more usage
```

When I try to use `--help` it gives me the same error. Can anyone help?

This is exactly what I typed in:

```
C:\Users\DylanW\Desktop\Games\Dylancraft\Dylancraft-Alpha 1.0>2to3 -w MineCraft.py
```

Comment: What is the output of `where 2to3`?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Just checked the source code of 2to3 and the message is here, behind an `if not args`.

Comment: Are you sure you're giving us exactly what you typed ? 2to3 whines about this message when no files are given, you're giving one. Can you copy/paste us your exact command ? Are you really using spaces between `-w` and `MineCraft.py` ?

Comment: @JulienPalard: I'm not sure I entirely understand your comment.  Perhaps you misunderstood mine?  The only way I know to reproduce this issue is to create a batch script named `2to3.bat` in the current directory which calls `2to3.py` without passing on the command-line arguments.  `where` is the Windows version of the Unix utility `which`, and `where 2to3` should reveal what Windows will actually run when you enter `2to3`.  In the situation I described, this shows up the batch file I mentioned.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Sry, I completly forgotten than Windows even existed. Forgive my ignorance about the "where" windows thing. Sincerely.